# MySQL UPDATE Value of column and ADD new value with old value

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a page that shows the leader board score for all users that have registered in the system, which is stored in my database.

**Table 1**:

`Points_hisotry` table:

```
| points_id || user_id(fk) || point_hist |
|___________||_____________||____________|
|      1    ||     10      ||    100     |  
|___________||_____________||____________|
|      2    ||     11      ||     30     |
|___________||_____________||____________|
|      3    ||     11      ||     70     |
|___________||_____________||____________|
|      4    ||     11      ||    200     |
```

**Table 2**:

`Users` Table:

```
| users_id ||  username || firstname  || lastname ||
|__________||___________||____________||__________||
|    10    ||   alan1   ||    Alan    ||  Smith   ||
|__________||___________||____________||__________||
|    11    ||   Jaz12   ||    Jass    ||  Hopal   ||
|__________||___________||____________||__________||
|    12    ||   Shubs   ||    shubs   ||  hawash  ||
|__________||___________||____________||__________||
|    13    ||   John    ||    Rob     ||  engli   ||
```

In the `points_history` table, I have 3 rows with the same `users_id` where I need them to be summed up so I end up with total `Point_hist` for that `users_id` which should add up to 300.

I need a query to help me join this tables, then sum the rows of the same `users_id` to one and print it out on my scoreboard.

I have tried plenty of queries, but I have not got it right.

Here is some of my PHP from **leaderboard.php**:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users, points_history WHERE users.users_id = points_history.users_id"; 
$user_query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($user_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $username = $row ["username"];
    $point_hist = $row["point_hist"];
```

The above query is to print out all of the `username`, and their points from the above two table.

I am new to this, so I need some help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUM()` to sum them up (who'd have thought), but you'll need to tell SQL via `GROUP BY` which rows to sum and which it shouldn't.

```
SELECT users.*, SUM(points_history.point_hist) AS total_points
FROM users
INNER JOIN points_history
    ON users.users_id = points_history.users_id
GROUP BY users_id
```

should do the trick

Comment: the above code works, but it gives me the total_points for the entire table to each user. rather than the total_points for each user to each user. @kingkero

Comment: I think I would need a `WHERE` condition to state `WHERE users.users_id = '$id'`  but how would I add that to the above query. @kingkero

Comment: @user3443701 Mhm in my [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17964a/6) it worked, maybe try `GROUP BY points_history.users_id`

Comment: @user3443701 If you want this for a specific user, you can add the `WHERE` before the `GROUP BY`

Comment: even with the `WHERE` it still giving me the actual total points rather than the individual users total points. @kingkero

Comment: @user3443701 Can you reproduce that behaviour in a fiddle?

Comment: have a look at my site `https://studentnet.kingston.ac.uk/k1003140/leaderboard.php` where all the users have 520 points and they shouldnt.

Comment: @user3443701 Seems like the `GROUP BY` isn't working properly. Sorry, but as long as you can' reproduce it in a fiddle I can't help you (I'm not that much of a SQL crack)

Comment: I don't know how to reproduce it. @kingkero